# pandas/python: splitting url and adding columns to a database

Tags: python, database, url, pandas, split

I have a one column database with several url of the form

> 'w.lejournal.fr/actualite/politique/sarkozy-terminator_1557749.html',
>
> 'w.lejournal.fr/palmares/palmares-immobilier/',
>
> 'w.lejournal.fr/actualite/societe/adeline-hazan-devient-la-nouvelle-controleuse-des-lieux-de-privation-de-liberte_1558176.html'

I want to create a 3 column database which first column contains these exact url, and the second column the principal category of the page (actualite, or palmares), and the third column containing the second category of the page (politique, or palmares-immobilier, or societe).

I can't give my code since I am not allowed to post urls.

I want to use python pandas.
Firstly: is this the good way to do it?
Secondly: how can I finish the concatenation?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by the second question but you could just split each url and then add them to a dict with the column name as keys and the values as the list of the values and you can construct a DataFrame using this dict

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for pandas, regex can do this quite efficiently:

```
import re

ts = ['w.lejournal.fr/actualite/politique/sarkozy-terminator_1557749.html',
    'w.lejournal.fr/palmares/palmares-immobilier/',
    'w.lejournal.fr/actualite/societe/adeline-hazan-devient-la-nouvelle-controleuse-des-lieux-de-privation-de-liberte_1558176.html']

rgx = r'(?<=w.lejournal.fr/)([aA-zZ]*)/([aA-zZ_-]*)(?=/)'

for url_address in ts:
    found_group = re.findall(rgx, url_address)
    for item in found_group:
        print item
```

this is what it returns:

```
('actualite', 'politique')
('palmares', 'palmares-immobilier')
('actualite', 'societe')
```

of course you wouldn't need to do this on a list of urls

Answer (score 1):

With pure Python:

```
data= [
    'w.lejournal.fr/actualite/politique/sarkozy-terminator_1557749.html',
    'w.lejournal.fr/palmares/palmares-immobilier/',
    'w.lejournal.fr/actualite/societe/adeline-hazan-devient-la-nouvelle-controleuse-des-lieux-de-privation-de-liberte_1558176.html'
]

result = []

for x in data:
    cols = x.split('/')
    result.append( [x, cols[1], cols[2]] )

print result
```

.

```
[
  ['w.lejournal.fr/actualite/politique/sarkozy-terminator_1557749.html', 'actualite', 'politique'], 
  ['w.lejournal.fr/palmares/palmares-immobilier/', 'palmares', 'palmares-immobilier'], 
  ['w.lejournal.fr/actualite/societe/adeline-hazan-devient-la-nouvelle-controleuse-des-lieux-de-privation-de-liberte_1558176.html', 'actualite', 'societe']
]
```

You have to only read and write to database.

---

If you have all urls started with `http://` than you will need to get `cols[3]`, `cols[4]`

```
data= [
    'http://w.lejournal.fr/actualite/politique/sarkozy-terminator_1557749.html',
    'http://w.lejournal.fr/palmares/palmares-immobilier/',
    'http://w.lejournal.fr/actualite/societe/adeline-hazan-devient-la-nouvelle-controleuse-des-lieux-de-privation-de-liberte_1558176.html'
]

result = []

for x in data:
    cols = x.split('/')
    result.append( [x, cols[3], cols[4]] )

print result
```

Comment: Thank you a lotfor this Pure Python version!